# Node ReferenceError on included helper class

Tags: javascript, node.js

When running the following code, I am getting a reference error which states that LinkedList is not defined when using ShelterQueue.enqueue(). However, I have defined LinkedList in the same file as ShelterQueue, and I reference it there by it's name, which makes me feel like it should be available.

Would anyone happen to be able to explain what is going wrong in this snippet?

cracking.js

```
LinkedList = function(data){
  this.data = data;
  this.next = null;

  this.addToEnd = function(data){
    n = this;
    while (n.next !== null){
      n = n.next;
    }
    var b = new LinkedList(data);
    n.next = b;
    return b;
  };
};

Dog = function(){};
Cat = function(){};

ShelterQueue = function(){
  this.cat = null;
  this.dog = null;
  this.all = null;

  this.enqueue = function(item){
    var node = null;
    if (this.all === null){
      node = new LinkedList(item);
      this.all = node;
    }
    else{
      node = this.all.addToEnd(item);
    }
    if (item instanceof Dog){
      if (this.dog === null){
        this.dog = node;
      }
    }
    else if (this.cat === null){
      this.cat = node;
    }
  };

  this.dequeueAny = function(){
    while (this.all !== this.cat && this.all == this.dog){
      this.all = this.all.next;
    }
    item = this.all;
    this.all = this.all.next;
    if (this.cat === item){
      this.cat = this.cat.next;
      while (!(this.cat instanceof Cat)){
        this.cat = this.cat.next;
      }
    }
    else{
      this.dog = this.dog.next;
      while(!(this.dog instanceof Dog)){
        this.dog = this.dog.next;
      }
    }
    return item;
  };

  this.dequeueType = function(name, type){
    var item = this[name];
    var next = item.next;
    while(!(next instanceof type) && next !== null){
      next = next.next;
    }
    this[name] = next;
    return item;
  };

  this.dequeueCat = function(){
    return this.dequeueType('cat', Cat);
  };

  this.dequeueDog = function(){
    return this.dequeueType('dog', Dog);
  };
};

exports.ShelterQueue = ShelterQueue;
exports.LinkedList = LinkedList;
exports.Cat = Cat;
exports.Dog = Dog;
```

test.js

```
var cracking = require('./cracking.js');

var shelter = new cracking.ShelterQueue();
shelter.enqueue(new cracking.Cat());
```

Comment: What is the error? can you show the error?

Comment: @DinhNC The error is: `ReferenceError: LinkedList is not defined at enqueue` and then a line number which corresponds to the line where enqueue creates a LinkedList.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I eventually ended up fixing it, but I'm not exactly sure how. I think it had something to do with originally defining my classes as functions.

Here is the fixed cracking.js

```
function LinkedList(data){
  this.data = data;
  this.next = null;
}

LinkedList.prototype.addToEnd = function(data){
  n = this;
  while (n.next !== null){
    n = n.next;
  }
  var b = new LinkedList(data);
  n.next = b;
  return b;
};

function Dog(){}
function Cat(){}

function ShelterQueue(){
  this.cat = null;
  this.dog = null;
  this.all = null;
}

ShelterQueue.prototype.enqueue = function(item){
  var node = null;
  if (this.all === null){
    node = new LinkedList(item);
    this.all = node;
  }
  else{
    node = this.all.addToEnd(item);
  }
  if (item instanceof Dog){
    if (this.dog === null){
      this.dog = node;
    }
  }
  else if (this.cat === null){
    this.cat = node;
  }
};

ShelterQueue.prototype.dequeueAny = function(){
  while (this.all !== this.cat && this.all == this.dog){
    this.all = this.all.next;
  }
  item = this.all;
  this.all = this.all.next;
  if (this.cat === item){
    this.cat = this.cat.next;
    while (!(this.cat instanceof Cat)){
      this.cat = this.cat.next;
    }
  }
  else{
    this.dog = this.dog.next;
    while(!(this.dog instanceof Dog)){
      this.dog = this.dog.next;
    }
  }
  return item;
};

ShelterQueue.prototype.dequeueType = function(name, type){
  var item = this[name];
  var next = item.next;
  while(!(next instanceof type) && next !== null){
    next = next.next;
  }
  this[name] = next;
  return item;
};

ShelterQueue.prototype.dequeueCat = function(){
  return this.dequeueType('cat', Cat);
};

ShelterQueue.prototype.dequeueDog = function(){
  return this.dequeueType('dog', Dog);
};

exports.ShelterQueue = ShelterQueue;
exports.LinkedList = LinkedList;
exports.Cat = Cat;
exports.Dog = Dog;
```

Comment: You should declare each module to each file. And need to reading more about Nodejs. 
Reference: https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: I felt your thoughts of coding style dependent C language. :)